# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files but ulimit already set high

Tags: python, flask, oserror

I am trying to make a small visualisation tool using Flask however I keep having the error

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

The error occurs when I add the python module "dependencies" import to the file.
The module works perfectly fine outside so I don't understand why I get this error

This is the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from dependencies.simulation import Simulation

app = Flask(__name__)

@app..route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have set my ulimit to

```
ulimit -n 10240
```

but it doesn't change anything

Any help would be great, I have already lost a lot of time on this !

Comment: (You can use `ulimit -n unlimited` to have unlimited files open, but it would be better to fix the root cause, of which I'm not sure.)

Comment: I tried with `ulimit -n unlimited` as well but doesn't work either

Comment: The problem would appear to be with the dependency you're adding. Where are you getting it from?